# How to properly TRIM an ssd (18.04)

Tags: ssd, trim

I want to do what follows:

1. set (via `systemctl`) a trim timer which would trim more than once a week but less than daily. Say every three days.
2. I want to be sure that if the system is turned off or sleeping what the scheduled trim should be executed, it will be executed at the next awakening/boot.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is TRIM enabled on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034169/is-trim-enabled-on-my-ubuntu-18-04-installation)

Comment: Thanks. However it doesn't seem to answer my question: "I want to be sure that if the system is turned off or sleeping what the scheduled trim should be executed, it will be executed at the next awakening/boot".

Answer (score 2):

Not a perfect solution, but as a stop-gap, you can manually trim on-demand via a command like `sudo /sbin/fstrim -av` **See below before running this; you want to make sure you get the right command!**

`systemctl cat fstrim.service` will show you the fstrim service file.

Look at the bottom and see what's being executed. You'll see this after the line `ExecStart=`. It will probably, for Ubuntu 18.04, be calling `/sbin/fstrim -av`.

With this in mind, run `sudo /sbin/fstrim -av` and you'll see something like

```
/boot: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
/: 6 GiB (6384705536 bytes) trimmed
```

Boom, trimmed!

And, yes, it doesn't ask the question you're **really** after, which is the same question I have after seeing this question. I'll look into this myself on my laptop and post back here--it'll help us both!