# Enable TRIM on secondary, encrypted ssd

Tags: encryption, ssd, automount, luks, trim

I have a smaller, LUKS-encrypted ssd. I want to help get longevity if I can. I'm not sure how TRIM comes into play for an encrypted drive. I've looked at this [Q&A on TRIM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034169/is-trim-enabled-on-my-ubuntu-18-04-installation), and my main drive is good.

The drive does not mount on bootup. I normally click the icon in the Other Places tab, enter the password, and mount the drive. I do not want to auto mount the drive on boot. Thank you.

> **update** -- trim is enabled on the primary ssd, with no entry for the other (unmounted) ssd. Can I mount the drive without decrypting, so as
>   to run the trim service? I'm curious about the line with `errors=remount-ro o 1` as well.
>
> ```
>  ~ systemctl status fstrim.timer
> ●[solid green] fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: active (waiting) since Sun 2019-04-14 06:03:18 CDT; 14h ago
>   Trigger: Mon 2019-04-15 00:00:00 CDT; 3h 38min left
>      Docs: man:fstrim
>
> Apr 14 06:03:18 home systemd[1]: Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
>
>  ~ systemctl status fstrim
> ●[solid white] fstrim.service - Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab
>    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
>    Active: inactive (dead)
>      Docs: man:fstrim(8)
>
>  ~ systemctl cat fstrim
> # /lib/systemd/system/fstrim.service
> [Unit]
> Description=Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab
> Documentation=man:fstrim(8)
>
> [Service]
> Type=oneshot
> ExecStart=/sbin/fstrim -Av
>
>  ~ cat /etc/fstab
> # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
> #
> # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
> # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
> # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
> #
> # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
> # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
> UUID=#############-####-####-########### /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
> /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure how TRIM comes into play for an encrypted drive.

Nowhere. TRIM is on the level of the file system. Encryption on the level of the data on the filesystem.

> The drive does not mount on bootup.

Also not important

See  [Is TRIM enabled on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034169/is-trim-enabled-on-my-ubuntu-18-04-installation)

> TRIM is enabled to run weekly by default in 18.04. It is a systemd service managed via systemctl.

If not enabled already you need to set it through /etc/fstab options if auto mount. Otherwise you can also use tune2fs to enable it for a manual mount. But it should already be set.

Comment: Will you look again? I've updated the question. Thank you.